# Child elements overflowing custom RelativeLayout

Tags: android, android-layout, android-view

I made a custom View that extends the `PercentRelativeLayout` and forces the View to be quadratic. The child elements of this view should match their parent's size (height and width). If I set the children's `layout_width` or `layout_height` to `match_parent` or `fill_parent` they extend over the parent View (as you can see in the right half of the picture). The child elements are not visible outside of the custom Layout, but I can't align the children via relative sizes properly.

[image: Children extending over parent]

The custom view:

```
public class QuadraticPercentRelativeLayout extends PercentRelativeLayout {

    public QuadraticPercentRelativeLayout(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    public QuadraticPercentRelativeLayout(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
    }

    public QuadraticPercentRelativeLayout(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {
        super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec);

        int width = getMeasuredWidth();
        int height = getMeasuredHeight();
        int size = width < height ? width : height;
        setMeasuredDimension(size, size);
    }
}
```

Here is my Layout (simplified):

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
                xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
                android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
                android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
                android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin">

    <QuadraticPercentRelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/progress_bar">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/page_view"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:scaleType="fitCenter"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/package_stock"/>

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/next_view"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/page_view"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            app:layout_widthPercent="35%"
            app:srcCompat="@color/ColorPrimaryDark"/>

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/previous_view"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/page_view"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            app:layout_widthPercent="35%"
            app:srcCompat="@color/ColorPrimaryDark"/>

    </QuadraticPercentRelativeLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Is this the standard behavior for children Views? How can I change it to make the children match the parent size?

Answer (score 0):

I fixed the onMeasure method in the `QuadraticPercentRelativeLayout` class:

```
@Override
protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {
    int width = MeasureSpec.getSize(widthMeasureSpec);
    int height = MeasureSpec.getSize(heightMeasureSpec);
    int size = Math.min(width, height);
    int measureSpec = MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(size, MeasureSpec.EXACTLY);
    super.onMeasure(measureSpec, measureSpec);
}
```